# Software updater

Tags: open-source, software-testing

I run a nonprofit offering free tech services to needy families. One thing I noticed was that my patch management solution was not updating all software on some clients computers. What I'm looking for is a tool that can run on their computer either automatically through a task scheduler or on command through my RMM program. This tool will search the computer for any third-party software that's installed on the computer, look to see if there's any updates for that software, and preferably automatically run the updates. I've tried things like chocolatey and winget as well as patch my PC. The problem with these solutions is they only search for software in their compatible software list.

What I'm looking for is something like the old file hippo update checker that scans your computer for what software you have and looks to see if there's updates for it. Not something that only looks for a few hundred pieces of software that are in their database. Does something like that exist anymore?

Comment: This question honestly makes 0 sense. FileHippo had a database as well and it was much smaller than e.g. Chocolatey's. There's no magical global solution as different software vendors manage their downloads/versions in completely different ways. E.g. a bunch release on GitHub, others publish installers on their websites, not always in a way that can be automated and some will even require logging in to download.